# Bubble pressure ascending?

Tags: pressure, bubbles

In water bubbles rise up to the surface.
As it rises, does the bubble's pressure decrease or stay the same?
I think stays the same.

Comment: Do you think the pressure inside the bubble will be greater than, less than or equal to the pressure of the water around the bubble?

Answer (score 0):

The pressure will decrease for two reasons. The pressure inside a bubble , $P_b$, is $P_b=P_{ext}+P_{ten}$, where $P_{ten}=2\gamma/R$ is the pressure added by the surface tension, $R$ is the radio of the bubble.

As the bubble goes up: 1)the external pressure diminishes and 2) The surface tension diminishes too because as the internal pressure diminishes the bubble expands ($R$ becomes larger) and the surface tension pressure also drops. So both terms that contribute to the pressure inside the bubble diminish.